# sonarqube error during running sonnar-scanner command

Tags: php, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to run `sonar-scanner`, but it seem there is some problems figuring in the image .

[image: exception in analysis log]

NB: this command work great with another project

Analysis log:

```
E:\wamp64\www\Ecco_Last>sonar-scanner C:\sonar-scanner\bin\.. 
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\sonar-scanner\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.pro perties 
INFO: Project root configuration file: E:\wamp64\www\Ecco_Last\sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.8
INFO: Java 1.8.0_91 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 7 6.1 amd64 
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\ALTEN\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load global repositories
INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=118ms WARN: Property 'sonar.jdbc.url' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There
is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\ALTEN\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=8ms
INFO: SonarQube server 5.6.6 
INFO: Default locale: "fr_FR", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=17ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=29ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=553ms
INFO: Publish mode 
INFO: -------------  Scan Ecco_Last
INFO: Language is forced to php
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=201ms 
INFO: Base dir: E:\wamp64\www\Ecco_Last
INFO: Working dir: E:\wamp64\www\Ecco_Last\.sonar
INFO: Source paths: application 
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: fr_FR
INFO: Index files 
WARN: Invalid character encountered in file E:\wamp64\www\Ecco_Last\application\modules\migrationfai\controller\LivraisonController.php at line 65 for encoding UTF-8. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using proper ty 'sonar.sourceEncoding'. 
WARN: Invalid character encountered in file E:\wamp64\www\Ecco_Last\application\modules\options\model\Bonus.php at line 139 for encoding UTF-8. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
INFO: 644 files indexed
INFO: Quality profile for php: Sonar way
INFO: JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : E:\wamp64\www\Ecco_Last\target\jac oco.exec
INFO: JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: E:\wamp64\www\Ecco_Last\target\jacoco-it.exec
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=188ms
INFO: Sensor NoSonar Sensor
INFO: Sensor NoSonar Sensor (done) | time=664ms
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
INFO: SCM provider for this project is: svn
INFO: 644 files to be analyzed
INFO: 0/644
files analyzed INFO:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE INFO:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 12.188s
INFO: Final Memory: 45M/233M INFO:
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error when executing blame for file application /Bootstrap.php
        at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java: 102)
        at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java: 59)
        at org.sonar.batch.scm.ScmSensor.execute(ScmSensor.java:86)
        at org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor. java:58)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61) 
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: unknown host svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/ecco/ecco/trunk/application/Bootst rap.php'
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:106)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:90)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:798)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:398)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:386)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:863)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:699)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:118)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1049)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.hasCapability(DAVRepository.java:877)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.assertServerIsMergeInfoCapable(SVNRepository.java:787)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.getFileRevisions(SVNRepository.java:756)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteAnnotate.run(SvnRemoteAnnotate.java:111)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteAnnotate.run(SvnRemoteAnnotate.java:35)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doAnnotate(SVNLogClient.java:295)
        at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:100)
        ... 32 more 
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: redmine.dev.dolmen.bouyguestelecom.fr
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createAddres(SVNSocketFactory.java:189)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createPlainSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:66)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:282)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:461)
        ... 48 more
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging
.

E:\wamp64\www\Ecco_Last>
```

Comment: Providing a screenshot of the error was a good start, but not enough of the error is shown. Please [edit] your question to include a copy-paste from `ERROR` to the end. Specifically, you should be sure to include the `Caused by` clause.

Comment: i think  it's ok  now ?

Answer (score 0):

This analysis failure was caused by the SVN client on the analysis server not being able to reach your SVN server:

```
UnknownHostException: redmine.dev.dolmen.bouyguestelecom.fr
```

You said analysis worked on a different project. Perhaps that project is on a different SCM server, or was analyzed from a different box. Nonetheless, you need to either clear up whatever network or configuration issue caused this communication failure or turn off the retrieval of blame data for this project: *Administration > General Settings > SCM > Disable the SCM Sensor*